# Why storing the StringBuffer object returned by the replace() method is not required?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

```
class replaceDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("This is a test.");

        sb.replace(5, 7, "was");
        System.out.println("After replace: " + sb);
   }
}
```

The replace() method returns a StringBuffer object then why that line is
not like this:

```
sb = sb.replace(5, 7, "was");
```

Why storing the object returned by the replace() is not required?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: What in the JavaDocs suggests that you need to assign the returned object to a variable? What is confusing? Reading?

Comment: This allows to chain several calls

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuffer` is *mutable* and the mutation is a *side effect* of the method `replace`.

On the other hand, `StringBuffer` has a *fluent API* which allows for "call chaining":

```
String test = new StringBuffer().append("some").append(" odd string").replace(5,8,"even").toString();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append("some");
stringBuffer.append(" odd string");
stringBuffer.replace(5, 8, "even");
String test = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: "method chaining", thats the usual name (just an info).

Comment: @Tom "method chaining" is *sooo last century...* ;o)

Answer (score 1):

StringBuffer is used to represent characters that can be modified.

replace operation manipulates the characters stored as char[] inside StringBuffer  and returns the current instance only.

so calling **sb = sb.replace(5, 7, "was")** is similar to  just calling **sb.replace(5, 7, "was")**

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary because `replace()` returns the CURRENT object, not a copy of the new object.

The behavior of the function is that it operates on the current object and does not create a new object.

> Returns:
>
> This object.

Note that is not a new object or a copy of the object but the current object after the operation has been complete.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)